# Transmission Cli Limit speed using terminal

Tags: ubuntu, file-transfer, bittorrent

I want to limit the download speed for some temporary time and then make it unlimited again. Scenario, I dont want the Transmission to take all bandwidth while surfing for 5 minutes. I wish to use Transmission CLI because I want to automate the whole process.

This is how I add the torrent file.

```
transmission-cli ~/Downloads/572403AA8726F9519C3897766B32F56C421681A4.torrent
```

But to limit the download speed.
First I have to do `CTRL`+`C` to pause the torrent
And then

```
transmission-cli -d 30 ~/Downloads/572403AA8726F9519C3897766B32F56C421681A4.torrent
```

to limit the speed.

Does anyone have a cleaner solution to this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using `transmission-cli` directly, run Transmission as a RPC server. `transmission-daemon` was created for this, but the GNOME Transmission app will work too.

```
$ transmission-daemon -g ~/.config/transmission
```

(An useful option is `--watch-dir ~/Downloads`, which automatically adds all `*.torrent` files found.)

You'll be able to use `transmission-remote` to control the server – add torrents, pause/resume, adjust speed:

```
$ transmission-remote --add ~/Downloads/*.torrent    (-a ...)
$ transmission-remote --downlimit 30                 (-d 30)
$ transmission-remote --no-downlimit                 (-D)
```

Transmission also has an "alternate speed" mode:

```
$ transmission-remote --alt-speed-downlimit 30       (-asd 30)
$ transmission-remote --alt-speed                    (-as)
$ transmission-remote --no-alt-speed                 (-AS)
```

Comment: after `transmission-daemon` and then `transmission-remote --add ~/Downloads/*.torrent` it gives the error. 
Unexpected response: <h1>401: Unauthorized</h1>Unauthorized Useroded

Comment: Try killing the daemon and restarting with `-T` option.

Comment: Did that, killed all process with the Transmission too. Didnt work out. Going to restart the computer and try again.

Comment: Tried it after restart. Still giving the same error. Maybe cli is default port is not the one on which Daemon is working

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6843978/nice-bittorrent-tracker-api
Got this link. Talks about authorization to use Daemon. But could not set up the Web Client from GUI too...

Answer (score 1):

The only way to set a download limit is to declare it at first using the **-d** option.
You can't temporarily set a downlimit while downloading **without** stopping and starting the process again.

If you can, use transmission-gtk which has the Alternative speed limit option and you can activate/deactivate it by a button.

Comment: `-d` flag is for Download

Answer (score 1):

this tutorial for transmission command

for download torrent link

```
transmission-remote -n 'transmission:transmission' -a eos-amd64-amd64-id-3.1.7-iso.torrent
```

for limit upload 5 kB/s

```
transmission-remote -n 'transmission:transmission' -u 5
```

for limit upload 10MB/s

```
transmission-remote -n 'transmission:transmission' -d 10000
```

for check config transmission

```
transmission-remote -n 'transmission:transmission' -si
```

for check current session/status torrent

```
transmission-remote -n 'transmission:transmission' -st
```